# DateTime and Stopwatch value comparison

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement, windows-phone-8, stopwatch

I'm trying to trigger the `Stopwatch.reset();` if the elapsed time is equal to the time value stored in a DateTime object `workDt` by using the .equals() to compare the elapsed time of the stopwatch with the time of day stored in my `DateTime` object `workDt.`

Basically the onTapped event triggers my Stopwatch to start and updates a textblock with the current elapsed time.

I've then passed a user inputted time value `"00 : 00 : 07 : 000"` to a DateTime object which I'm aiming to use for the comparison. The problem is I the condition is never met to trigger myStopwatch.reset();

In testing I set the string as follows which I then set a break point on the workDt and it shows the correct time is being stored but it doesn't trigger the condition.

```
private async void startBtn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {

            //delay stop watch start to allow time to get ready.
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(time);


            string wrkString;
            string rstString; 
            int i;

            //set text box editing to false to prevent illegal input.
            wrkTbx.IsEnabled = false;
            restTbx.IsEnabled = false;
            roundSlider.IsEnabled = false;
            roundsTbx.IsEnabled = false;


            //Assign text box time string to string variables.
            wrkString = wrkTbx.Text;
            rstString = restTbx.Text;


            //Assign text box string value to a date time variable.

            DateTime workDt = DateTime.ParseExact(wrkString.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime restDt = DateTime.ParseExact(rstString.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //Run the timer for until i reaches the number of rounds value.Eg, 4 rounds
            //for (i = 0; i <= roundSlider.Value; i++ )
            //{

                StopGoCvs.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                //startSoundElmt.Play();
                // set up the timer
                myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
                myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;


                // start both timers
                myTimer.Start();
                myStopwatch.Start();

                //reset timer if date time value is equal to current elapsed time.
                if(myStopwatch.Elapsed.Equals(workDt.TimeOfDay))
                {

                    myStopwatch.Reset();

                }






        }
```

Is this the correct way to achieve this or should I be using a different method?

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to achieve here. You're comparing the time spent doing against the exact time of day. Unless you started the action at exactly midnight, the two will never match. I think you should reconsider what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: The workDt is a DateTime variable. It's time value is a string from a textbox. So for example, user enter in textbox: 00 : 00 : 07 : 000, the time value of workDt will now be 7 seconds. I want to stop the stopwatch when it reaches for example 7 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chances of the elapsed time being *exactly* the same as the required time - down to the tick - are tiny.

Instead, you should see whether *at least* the right amount of time has passed:

```
if (myStopwatch.Elapsed >= workDt.TimeOfDay)
```

However, the place that you're checking that is inappropriate - you're checking *just* after starting the timer. Shouldn't you be checking it *in the timer tick event*?

Answer (score 1):

A timespan will only be equal if the times are equal to tick precision (ignoring arguments about tick refresh rate etc).

If you want to persevere with this approach you would want to know when the stopwatch transitions over the time of day (or is within a time window around the `TimeOfDay`).

But there is likely a more elegant way to achieve this by starting some work off and using a timer to fire an event at the correct time that modifies the work that is being done. (But more code would have to be posted to state what this should look like).